# how to convert mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in java

Tags: java, date, format

i am getting input date as String into mm/dd/yyyy and want to convert it into yyyy-mm-dd
i try out this code

```
Date Dob = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(request.getParameter("dtDOB"));
```

Comment: Ok, so you parsed it...Now format it.

Answer (score 7):

OK - you've fallen for one of the most common traps with java date formats:

- `mm` is *minutes*
- `MM` is *months*

You have parsed months as minutes. Instead, change the pattern to:

```
Date dob = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(...);
```

Then to output, again make sure you use `MM` for months.

```
String str = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(dob);
```

Comment: Hey @Bohemian, congrats for the Diamond :)

Comment: thanx but this code not working.. that gives below error
Unparseable date: "03/19/2014"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)

Comment: @AnkitJain the cause is plain from the error messags: your input has slashes instead of dashes between the date parts. Try using pattern `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

Comment: @RohitJain hey thanks! I hope to see a diamond next to your name next year. You're a great contributor. I remember when you started you posted high-quality answers, and I thought to myself at the time that you would go far here. I was right.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

capital **M**

For More info refer  [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to parsing you can use regex

```
s = s.replaceAll("(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)", "$3-$2-$1");
```

Comment: A clever alternative to creating date-time objects.

Answer (score 1):

Ex -

```
String dob = "05/02/1989";  //its in MM/dd/yyyy
String newDate = null;
Date dtDob = new Date(dob);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

try {
      newDate = sdf.format(dtDob);
} catch (ParseException e) {}

System.out.println(newDate); //Output is 1989-05-02
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class FormatDate {

  private SimpleDateFormat inSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
  private SimpleDateFormat outSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

  public String formatDate(String inDate) {
    String outDate = "";
    if (inDate != null) {
        try {
            Date date = inSDF.parse(inDate);
            outDate = outSDF.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException ex) 
            System.out.println("Unable to format date: " + inDate + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return outDate;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FormatDate fd = new FormatDate();
    System.out.println(fd.formatDate("12/10/2013"));
  }

}
```

Comment: thanx to all for ur solution...