# Joda Time - Wrong Result

Tags: java, date, jodatime

Can anyone tell me why this test is failing? I tried normal Java Date util and it also gave me the same result.

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected: Wed Jan 01 00:07:00 CET 2014 but
>   was: Fri Jan 31 00:06:00 CET 2014

```
public static Date addDaysToDate(Date fromDate, int days){       
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(fromDate);
    return dateTime.plusDays(days).toDate();
}

@Test
public void test() throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    Date fromDate = sdf.parse("2014-06-30");

    Date toDate = DateUtil.addDaysToDate(fromDate, 1);
    assertEquals(sdf.parse("2014-07-01"), toDate);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111209/how-to-convert-mm-dd-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to consult the [API Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and ensure that the format you are using is correct for the data you are parsing...

Change `yyyy-mm-dd` to `yyyy-MM-dd`

`mm` is used for minutes